# Activate a trigger animation with a macro in order to add animations without resetting a presentation already running

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found out that everytime I activate a macro to add a new animation, all presentation timings restart.
If I work in the same powerpoint presentation I can use the trigger animation, but in that case I have to work on different PowerPoint presentations communicating with each others, thus forced to use Macros.

I tried with making a shape appears or disappears and in this way it worked :

```
Presentations(currentPPTName).Slides(AnimationSlide).Shapes(shapeName).Visible = msoTrue
```

The animations in the "currentPPTName" keep running without problems, but if I add an animation like a simple translation, everything stops.

I suppose, therefore, that adding a new animation with a macro is not the solution I need, but perhaps I should keep the trigger as a valid solution:

Is there a way to activate a trigger with a macro?

Thank you,

Niccolò